# How to open port ttyAMA0 on Debian

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, tty

I have a raspberry pi 4 with debian bullseye installed on it. I want to open port ttyAMA0, how can I do it?

I have manually installed raspi-config and tried:
Interface Options -> Serial Port -> NO -> YES, reboot

This seems to add enable_uart=1 to /boot/config.txt ( I don't have anything else )

I tried adding dtoverlay=disable-bt

I cannot manage so far, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.